# Orbeon 3.9 ANY User Interaction with form triggers a java.lang.NullPointerException Error

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, orbeon, mod-jk

We have a PHP app that uses Orbeon in the background to display forms to the users,
Recently we had to come up with the solution for people with the 8080 port blocked so we have installed the jk_mod to serve Tomcat webapps in the vhost file as:

```
JkMount /orbeon/* geronimo_ajp13
JkMount /ops/* geronimo_ajp13
```

Users are able to open Orbeon documents but as soon as they perform any Orbeon action (click in the table, submit form etc.) they get following Orbeon error:

[image]

Here is my Firebug response (200 ok) when Orbeon action gets triggered:

[image]

And here is the orbeon.log error triggered:

```
    2012-06-21 12:19:21,796 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Received request
2012-06-21 12:19:21,866 ERROR ProcessorService  - Exception at line 55, column 65 of oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-server.xpl (reading processor output: name='response', id='x
forms-response')
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager.checkUUIDInSession(XFormsStateManager.java:92)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager.findOrRestoreDocument(XFormsStateManager.java:277)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer.doIt(XFormsServer.java:152)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer.access$000(XFormsServer.java:56)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer$1.readImpl(XFormsServer.java:88)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:263)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:406)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:260)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.TeeProcessor$TeeProcessorOutputImpl.readImpl(TeeProcessor.java:89)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:263)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:406)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:260)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsTinyTree(ProcessorImpl.java:286)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl$3.read(ProcessorImpl.java:315)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:365)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:330)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsTinyTree(ProcessorImpl.java:313)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteChooseProcessor.start(ConcreteChooseProcessor.java:186)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$5.run(PipelineProcessor.java:661)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.executeChildren(PipelineProcessor.java:726)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.start(PipelineProcessor.java:658)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteChooseProcessor.start(ConcreteChooseProcessor.java:248)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$5.run(PipelineProcessor.java:661)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.executeChildren(PipelineProcessor.java:726)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.start(PipelineProcessor.java:658)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.pipeline.InitUtils.runProcessor(InitUtils.java:89)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService.service(ProcessorService.java:97)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServletDelegate.service(OrbeonServletDelegate.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Does anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error clearly indicates that a session cookie is not propagated for some reason. I would check into that.

Comment: Hi, was messing with the Cookies for a good while today (looked suspicious, that's true), but at least I know now to dive deeper into it, thanks for the clue!

Comment: Our Orbeon Ajax requests headers show that the "Expires" is the same as "Date", these values did differ before going with the mod_jk for Apache (when all worked smoothly),

Does that mean that the Orbeon Ajax requests time out straight away?

And if yes - do you have any idea where we can manually set the "Expires" value to be a future-time?

Thanks,
We are trying to solve this issue for a week now and we are really stuck...

Comment: Expires == Date is normal for Ajax requests, since it doesn't make
sense for the browser to cache the result from an Ajax request. I
really don't think this is the source of your troubles. But you might want to check that JSESSIONID is correctly sent by the browser in those Ajax requests.

Comment: That's right. That header is a caching header, not a timeout header. It would be wrong to set it to a future date. This said the Ajax requests are POSTs, for which caching wouldn't apply.

Comment: Managed to solve the issue, turned out that apart from JSESSIONID value I had to set the Cookie Path to /orbeon/xforms-server and now it's all working like a charm,
PHP code for that would be something along those lines:
`setcookie('JSESSIONID', value-of-jsessionid-without-semicolon, time()+3600*24*2, '/orbeon/xforms-server');`
Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, glad to rad this. @avernet also posted a [blog entry](http://blog.orbeon.com/2012/06/the-right-cookie.html) on this topic.